Subsets of groups that contain a (large) coset
Let $G$ be a group.
Suppose that finitely many translates of $A\subseteq G$ cover $G$.
Does $A$ contain the coset of a subgroup with finite index?
[If the answer is no, I'd appreciate references to understand the property containing the coset of a subgroup of finite index]

How is my question related to Neumann 's Theorem? Could you give me a hint?

N.B. The question says $A\subseteq G$ not $A\leq G$. And it does not assume $G$ abelian.
